What is the difference between a model and an interpretation in logic?
On page 319 of Irving M. Copi's 'Symbolic Logic', he states, "if we want our logical system to be applicable to any possible universe, regardless of the exact number of individuals it contains there is no N_j such that we want N_j or ~N_j provable as theorems, where N_j is the statement that there are at most j individuals.
Then on page 320 he states "instead of continuing to speak of 'possible universes', we shall talk about models, where a model is any non-empty collection of elements each of which is thought of as an individual. And instead of speaking of our system of logic as being applied to a possible universe, we shall speak of a model as constituting an interpretation of our formal system."
Then he gives a rather complicated definition of an interpretation.
This is all done to prove the completeness of the first order function calculus RS_1.  What I'm wondering, is whether or not there is a simpler definition of interpretation than the one offered by Copi, and whether his definition of the term 'model' is the same one that appears in the statement, "A logical constant is a symbol of symbolic logic that has the same meaning in all models"?

Model is relative to a set T of formulas: it is an interpretation that satisfy all formulas of T.

The terms are often confused. A model/interpretation for a Language of Predicate Calculus is an Ordered Pair (X,I) where X is a set and I is an interpretation function. A model of a Theory (Set of Sentences) is an interpretation of a Language, which satisfies every sentence in the Theory.

If the interpretation function  isn't mentioned explicitly, most likely they mean the standard interpretation. I.E. if it's in the context of Set Theory, we interpret ∈ in the usual way. ( such models are called ∈-models) If it's Arithmetic, we interpret 1,0, <,+ in the usual way etc...

Yes, it is the same notion of model as used in "A logical constant is a symbol of..."

Unfortunately, those terms are used in different ways by different logicians. It is fairly standard to say that an interpretation of a sentence in a formal language is an assignment of meanings to its terms, i.e. an interpretation assigns a referent to names, classes to predicates and functions, truth values to propositional variables. A model of a sentence is an interpretation under which the sentence is true.
By extension we can also speak of interpretations and models of entire theories, i.e. of classes of sentences. So an interpretation of a theory is one that provides an interpretation for all its sentences, and a model of a theory is an interpretation under which all of its sentences are true.
So for example, a sentence Fa may have many interpretations. If we take our domain to be the real world, and interpret the predicate F to mean "is a professional football player", and the name a to mean Lionel Messi, then that interpretation is a model of that sentence, since the sentence is true under that interpretation. If instead we interpret a to mean Gordon Ramsey, the sentence would be false under that interpretation and so the interpretation would not be a model of it.
However, some writers use model and interpretation interchangeably, which is rather confusing. Also, interpretation is sometimes used in a broader sense to refer to the relation under which one structure can be mapped into another.

In your rather learned opinion, is interpretation nothing more than an attempt at rational (as in consistent) variable binding of tokens to meanings, which themselves construed as linearized collections of tokens masquerading as definienda and definientia?

In the extended sense, an interpretation, or sometimes a relative interpretation, refers to the ability of one structure to interpret another, or one theory to interpret another. This amounts to saying that there exists a syntactic relation that provides a mapping in such a way that definitions and theorems are preserved. A simple example is that a complex number can be interpreted as an ordered pair of real numbers.

Graham Priest says in p. 121 that model, interpretation, structure and situation are the same notion.

In Ebbinghaus 2021, the four important terms regarding the semantics of a language are a structure, an assignment, an interpretation, and a model.
An alphabet consists of eight distinct groups of symbols: quantifiers, variables, constants, functions, relations, punctuation, logical symbols, and equality.
When we supply rules for constructing terms and formula from those symbols, we have a language. This is basically like a grammar. In model theory, variables, constants, and functions are terms; and relations are formula.
A structure is a map from the function symbols, relation symbols, and constant symbols of the alphabet to some actual functions, relations and values, in some semantic domain.
When we have a structure, we are now closer to knowing what referents the terms of the language refer to.
An assignment is a mapping of the variables to specific values. (I am now realizing I do not know how this interacts with quantifiers).
An interpretation is a structure with an assignment. When we have an interpretation, we now know everything the language is saying, so we can determine if a given formula written in the language says something true or not.
A model of a formula just means a structure which makes the formula true (for all possible variable assignments). You can think of it intuitively as a structure for which the formula is universally true!
We recycle the same term ‘model’ for sets of formulae: if we find a structure (by interpreting components of a language as referring to particular things); and if all the formulae in a set of formulae are true (for all possible values of the variables); we say that that structure is a model of that set of formula. The model is just an example of something which the formula describe meaningfully.
Copi calls a “model” what Ebbinghaus calls a “structure”. Ebbinghaus considers a model a structure which actually interprets a set of formula well. But Copi considers a model “any semantic assignment for the language, whether it is a good one or not.”





An interpretation would be valid with respect to a WFF, not a language, wouldn't it?

@david gudeman, on page 320 Copi states Now we define interpretation of a WFF S with respect to a given model as an assignment of meanings such that, etc. Then further down he says, "An interpretation of a system with respect to a given model is an assignment of meanings which provides normal interpretations for all WFFS of the system.

@julius, if a structure maps constant symbols of the language to actual values, would that apply to the universal and existential quantifiers as well?  They are constants but they don't map to values.  Does he mean," map individual constants to values"?

@DavidGudeman I am definitely missing something; still learning. I realized I don’t know where the axioms of a theory enter the picture; and a model is something that satisfies a theory, not a language (I think). I’ll keep reading Ebbinghaus.

@leepappas In Ebbinghaus’s presentation, quantifiers are not constants. The presentation of a language begins with the presentation of an alphabet. An alphabet is precisely 7 named groups of symbols: constants, functions, relations, quantifiers, equality, logical symbols, and punctuation. (I think). Members of these groups do not overlap. Their use and character becomes clear when we receive the rules for how we map different symbol groups to different things in the semantic domain / domain of discourse. Quantifiers and logical symbols are not part of that mapping. Their meaning is fixed.

Actually it’s 8 groups of symbols - I forgot variables. And I resolved the question about model of a theory vs. a language: a model is a satisfactory interpretation of a formula, or of a set of formula. So we would never have a model of a language. We would have a model of formula written in a particular language.

@leepappas, you have three different layers, the logic, the theory, and the individual WFF (Well-Formed Formula). A theory is a set of WFFs closed under deduction. The quantifiers and connectives have meanings assigned by the rules of the logic. The constant, relation, and function symbols have a fixed meaning within a theory. I would have said that this meaning is provided by a model, and individual WFFs have in addition an assignment, but Julius's description might be more standard.

@julius, Copi seems to have this: possible universe=possible universe of discourse = possible domain of discourse=Possible models=possible sets of individuals.  Ebbinghaus defines a structure as a map from the function, relation, and constant symbols to some referents that are functions, relations, and values.  Are the latter all 'individuals' according to Copi?

@leepappas I’m going to check out Copi and see, I just downloaded it.

@david, when you say the constants have a fixed meaning in the theory, I'm confused.  'Socrates' could be a constant, an individual constant, but it's just a name, so how can a name have meaning?  I guess I'm confused about use of the term meaning.  I just understand the meaning of words, and the meaning of sentences.  But 'Socrates'' is a word without meaning, because it's a name.  The bulk of individual constants are just names.

@leepappas Initially, you are correct - a constant symbol like “Socrates” has zero meaning. It’s just an identifier, like declaring a variable in a programming language. However, when you choose a structure, you are going to have to decide what ‘Socrates’ refers to - and at that point, the meaning of “Socrates” will not change. So Gudeman means that while you are free to re-interpret the language in various structures, within each of those structures, a constant’s meaning is fixed and does not change - that’s why it’s called a ‘constant’; unlike a variable, whose value can change.

@julius, I understood everything you said, except one thing.  You said, when you choose a structure you are going to have to decide what 'Socrates'' refers to - and at that point the meaning of 'Socrates'' will not change.  Don't you mean, "at that point the referent will not change.  The referrer 'Socrates'' is meaningless

@leepappas "how can a name have meaning?" It refers to a that which it names. From Google: to mean - "intend to convey, indicate, or refer to (a particular thing or notion); signify." In the case of names, which are shared by multiple people, context and other explicit information helps us to refer correctly. If there is, for instance, confusion about which Diogenes, we can refer to his city of origin. If there is, for instance, confusion about which William Smith's taxes in the US, we can use his social security number. Names mean what they identify. Meaning by id is a form of signification.
